# Torrent in Windows phone

Tags: apps, store, nokia-lumia-535

I can't find other than a torrent search engine in windows store. Is it possible to download movies and all through torrent in windows phone too?

Or any other facility that we got to do so.

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic. But since I do happen to know of something, try this: https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/store/apps/wpTorrent/9WZDNCRFJ4CW .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Torrex Pro. Is a universal app, ready for mobile and desktop.
The store link is [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/torrex-pro/9wzdncrdsgkg).

Comment: I will let you kow.

Comment: It is not free :D I downloaded the Torrex Lite. Reviews are fine here.

Answer (score 1):

I've used `wpTorrent` for a while. You can give it a [try](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/wptorrent/9wzdncrfj4cw).

Comment: Ok lets see :) I will give it a try.